# Script to add comma with Application.Selection not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I originally found a script online that would let me add a comma at every X character, the problem was it only worked one selection at a time and I need to do this for 9000 times.

I started to play around with it, I'm pretty close to getting it to work properly but I would kindly need some assistance.

Right now when I switch the "next s" & "Loop" it works - But It formats it this way.

XXXXX,,XXXX,X,

I want it to look something like this:

XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX

And one thing I could most likely fix with a function after but it adds a comma at the end and would like for it to not add one at the end word.

Here's my script:

```
Sub CommaAdd()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim s As Range
    Dim x As Long

    xTitleId = "SelectionRange"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each s In WorkRng

    s = Selection.Value

    x = Len(s) \ 5
    If Len(s) Mod 5 = 0 Then
        x = x - 1
    End If
    Do Until x <= 0
        s = Left(s, x * 5) & "," & Mid(s, x * 5 + 1)
        x = x - 1
    Selection.Value = s
    Next s
    Loop
End Sub
```

The way it sits right now I get this error:

> Next without For

Any Ideals?

Edit:

I've tried this and now realized that all it does it copies the data from the first selection throughout the whole Column - Every individual cell has different data.

```
Sub CommaAdd()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim s As Range
    Dim x As Long

    xTitleId = "SelectionRange"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    For Each s In WorkRng


    x = Len(s) \ 5
    If Len(s) Mod 5 = 0 Then
        x = x - 1
    End If



    Do Until x = 0
        s = Left(s, x * 5) & "," & Mid(s, x * 5 + 1)
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    Selection.Value = s.Value
    Next s
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error got it working the way i Wanted. Thought I'd share

```
Sub CommaAdd()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim a As Object
    Dim x As Long

    xTitleId = "SelectionRange"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each a In WorkRng
    s = a.Value
    x = Len(s) \ 5
    If Len(s) Mod 5 = 0 Then
        x = x - 1
    End If
    Do Until x = 0
        s = Left(s, x * 5) & "," & Mid(s, x * 5 + 1)
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    a.Value = s
    Next a
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```